# validation on server side control using validate.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

i have asp text box and button control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" CssClass="sfInputbox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="Server" Text="Save"  ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

i want to validate textbox using `validate.js` when button is clicked.
i try inside `document.ready`:

```
        var btnSave = '<%=btnSave.ClientID%>';
        var txtFName = '<%=txtFName.ClientID %>';

        var v = $("#form1").validate({
            ignore: ':hidden',
            rules: {
                txtFName: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                txtLinkTitle: "<br/>First Name should not be blank"
            }

        });
        if (v.form()) {
            $('#' + btnSave).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }else
                $('#' + btnSave).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

But its not work.Don't suggest server side validation.Its my project demand.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i have understood the question, you can try

```
if ($("#form1").valid()) {
  //do something
```